# Convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to day and month

Tags: qt, date, qml, qtquick2

I've got dates in string format in my qml/javascript app. I would like to convert 2016-01-30 12:00:00 to something short and clear like 30 Jan 2016 12h. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code. Did you tried some of this mabye: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp ?

Comment: @krzysiej—please don't reference w3schools, the advice there is generally not very good. MDN is much preferred, as is the ECMAScript specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do in QML. Here's a sample that prints the exact string you wanted:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Item {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var date = new Date("2016-01-30 12:00:00")
        // Prints "30 Jan 2016 12h"
        console.log(Qt.formatDateTime(date, "dd MMM yyyy h'h'"))
    }
}
```

The `Date` object is just a standard JS date (with a few QML-specific extensions) and can parse many date strings into a date using the constructor. Read the [MDN documentation for `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more details.

`Qt.formatDateTime()` is a Qt-specific method used for formatting dates. It excepts a few different standard format types or you can pass your own format, as I did here. Read the [`Qt.formateDateTime()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#formatDateTime-method) documentation for more details. You'll also find a table of date format specifiers you can use.